# Android Fragments: removeAllViews in onDestroyView

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, view, ui-thread

My fragment has the reference to a `RelativeLayout` **mContentLayout**.

In `onDestroyView()` (before navigating to another fragment), I need to remove all views of this mContentLayout.

I know that you should deal with UI stuff only from the UI thread, but considering the layout is not visible anymore, would it make sense to call

```
mContentLayout.removeAllViews()
```

from a **separate thread**, so that the views removal doesn't block the UI thread?

Comment: No.  Removing all views triggers a layout pass which will trigger a new draw pass. It should be fast though.  I removes all views, remeasures, then draws in a single flow.

Comment: What about just calling `removeAllViewsInLayout()` ?
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L4343

Comment: That will wait until a layout pass to actually remove the views, but it's the same amount of time in any case.  I'm 99% certain that calling any of that calling any of these methods will lead to a crash regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I always stick with the guideline that if there is a good rule of thumb to stick to it. It was there for a reason.

For this particular case, I would believe that you wouldn't need to use a separate thread to perform this. The UI thread should be able to clear and redraw just fine. DeeV said the same thing in your comments.